# Cannot install github for windows

Tags: windows, git, windows-7, github

I'm getting an error and can't install github for windows.

> The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK
>   to close the application.

Afterwards IE opens and redirects me to http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application but nothing happens.

I'm running Windows 7 64bit.

Comment: Did you try downloading the installation file again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**Advanced Computer User Solution (manual update):**

```
1) Start your computer and log on as an administrator.
2) Click the Start button then select All Programs, Accessories, System Tools, and then click System Restore.
3) In the new window, select "Restore my computer to an earlier time" option and then click Next.
4) Select the most recent system restore point from the "On this list, click a restore point" list, and then click Next.
5) Click Next on the confirmation window.
6) Restarts the computer when the restoration is finished.
```

**Novice Computer User Solution (completely automated):**

```
1) Download (0xc000007b) repair utility.
2) Install program and click Scan button.
3) Click the Fix Errors button when scan is completed.
4) Restart your computer.
```

From [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/96035692-9a50-40d4-a7d3-48bda87d11ec/the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc000007b-click-ok-to-close-the-application-when).